# Proof of theorem, multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

The following theorem was presented in my textbook without proof and I would be thankful if someone could refer me to a proof of it:

Suppose that $ \boldsymbol{X} \sim N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Lambda}) $, where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ can be partitioned as follows:

\begin{pmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\Lambda_1} & \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0} \\
  \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda_2} & \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0} \\
  \boldsymbol{0}  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0} & \cdots & \boldsymbol{\Lambda_n}
 \end{pmatrix}

(possibly after reordering the components), where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_1}, \dots, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_n}$ are matrices along the diagonal of $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$. Then $\boldsymbol{X}$ can be partitioned into vectors $\boldsymbol{X^{(1)}},\boldsymbol{X^{(2)}},\dots,\boldsymbol{X^{(n)}}$ with $Cov(\boldsymbol{X^{(i)}})=\boldsymbol{\Lambda_i}$, $i=1,\dots,n$ in such a way that these random vectors are independent.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that jointly normal random variables are independent iff they have 0 correlation?

Comment: Yes, proof of that theorem is in the book.

Comment: The theorem follows directly from that.  That the covariance of $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(i)}$ is 0 implies that they are independent.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks!